# Limit and ln switch

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+1/x}{\sqrt{1-1/x+1/x^2}}\right) ?$$  I've seen this way of rewriting, but I can't see why it's equal.

Comment: The two expressions are equal because $\ln$ is a continuous function, and continuous functions preserve limits.

Comment: $$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2-x+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^2}{1-\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}}}$$  $$=\frac{1+\frac1x}{\sqrt{1-\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}}}$$

Comment: And because the limit of what's inside the $\ln$ is in the domain of $\ln$.

Comment: As to why continuous functions preserve limits see my answer to a related question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500867/why-is-lim-x-to-cgfx-g-lim-x-to-cfx/501054#501054)

Answer (score 3):

We know that if $f(u(x))$ is continuous function, then $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(u(x))=f\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}u(x)\right)$

Eg: $f(u(x))=\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\right)$ is a continuous function!