# Give an example where $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$, $\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=c$ but $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))\neq c$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Give an example where $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$, $\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=c$ but $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))\neq c$.

I got pretty stuck on this one. I thought maybe I can define the function $f(x)$ to only produce rational numbers like $f(x)=\left \lceil{x}\right \rceil $ which is basically a staircase function. Then $\lim\limits_{x \to a}=\left \lceil{a}\right \rceil $. And then I wanted to define some second function $g$ such that it doesn't take rational inputs. However this doesnt work because then the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to b}g(x)$ does not exist for any $b \in \mathbb R$.

In short, my attempt failed miserably. Then for any continuous function $f$ I am pretty sure that it doesn't work. If anyone could help me on my way that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(f(x))\neq c$, not $a$.

Comment: Indeed, just spotted it too and edited, Thanks

Comment: I checked again and the question is word for word what it says in the book (Introduction to Metric & Topological Spaces by Wilson A. Sutherland.)

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was proven wrong. Sorry for misleading you. Hagen posted the counterexample you need.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **seems** that no such counterexample should be possible.
However, note that the definition of $\lim_{x\to x_0}h(x)=y$ is:

> For $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $\color{red}{0<}|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have $|h(x)-y|<\epsilon$.

See if you can make something from this if yout let $f(x)=b$ constant and $g$ not continuous at $b$.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand now. So for instance if I let $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ where $x\neq 0$ and $g(x)=0$ when $x=0$ and take $a=0$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461636/what-fails-in-this-proof-of-limits/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/a/461426/72031 for another discussion and a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [here](http://www.unimathematics.com/808/analysis/limits-of-compositions) a very nice discussion with examples.