# Question regarding the proof of chain rule using the $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Using the following definition of derivative:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

I am trying to prove the chain rule, that is:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}}  \times\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

However, I don't understand where we get the definition of derivative in terms of two functions (colored in red). So that:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)} = \frac{df(g(x))}{d(x)} \times\frac{dx}{dg(x)}$$

$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(g(x+h)) - f(g(x))}{h} \times \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h }{g(x+h) - g(x)}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ f(g(x+h)) - f(g(x))}{g(x+h) - g(x)}  $$

From which the relation is easy to see. How is this definition/equality derived?¨

$-----------------------$

EDIT:

Here is an attempt but there may still be problems. First note that the term (again in red) is defined as first taking the derivative and then evaluating it at $g(x)$. So we replace every x in $f'(x)$ with $g(x)$. However this should the same as replacing every occurrence of x with $g(x)$ right in the beginning (Admittedly an argument with less hand-waving would be preferable).

As such the red term is equivalent to:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(g(x)+h) - f(g(x))}{h}$$

Now substitute $h = g(x)-g(x+h)$

$$\lim_{g(x)-g(x+h) \rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(g(x+h) - f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)}$$

Which is equivalent to:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(g(x+h) - f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)}$$

Comment: I'm confused. Are you unsure how the red part is derived, or how the red part translates into the limit given in the last line?

Comment: @KennyB How it translates to the last line / what the actual expression behind it is / whether the first formula can be used to work with such expression.

Comment: [Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) $f(a+x)= f(a)+ x f'(a)+ o(x), g(b+x) = g(b)+x g'(b)+o(x)$ and look at $g(f(a+x))$

Comment: What you're doing is wrong since $g(x+h) - g(x)$ might be zero for arbitrarily small $h$

Comment: Not sure if this helps, https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/taking-derivatives-calc/chain-rule-proof-calc/v/chain-rule-proof

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 And that is quickly covered by [Spivak](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731216/spivaks-chain-rule-proof-image-of-proof-provided?rq=1) $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Such case is outside of this analysis ;).

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/570077/72031

Answer (score -1):

$\require{cancel}$

Perhaps look at it this way:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}}  \times\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

How we got the quantity in red is because notice how the denominator $\color{red}{dg(x)}$ cancels with the numerator in the next term. So we have that:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{\cancel{dg(x)}}}  \times\frac{\cancel{dg(x)}}{dx}$$

Basically, we have the following:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}  \times 1$$

$$1 =\frac{dg(x)}{dg(x)} $$

Hence we get:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}}  \times\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

Simply by moving around the denominator. We "get" this because it's required to cancel out terms, which you see further in your chain rule proof. I don't think it's as important that you understand "where it came from", rather then "why it's here and how it's applied"

Comment: @K split X Aha, but now the "infinitesimal" definition of derivative is used. There is no division in the definition I use, so canceling terms is impossible.

Comment: @Tony you aren't really cancelling terms. It's just a way to look at how it works.

Comment: @Tony, what kenny is saying is correct

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think I see the confusion here:
$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}}  \times\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$
In order to use the definition of a derivative you have, it is easier to find the derivative w.r.t. x rather than g(x)
$$\frac{df(\color\red{g(x)})}{d\color\red{x}}$$

To remedy this we use a property of derivatives, that is, for example:
$$\frac{df(z)}{dx} = \frac{df(z)}{dz} \times  \frac{dz}{dy} \times \frac{dy}{dx}$$

We can carry on this process as needed, provided these terms hold. In your case $$\frac{dx}{dg(x)}$$ can be found in terms of the definition of a derivative you have been given.

EDIT: So I added your chain rule, plus the red term that is confusing you right. But I'll add colours so you can see how they came to that term.

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}}  \times\frac{dg(x)}{dx} ----- (1)$$

$$\color\red{\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}} = \color\green{\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} \times\frac{dx}{dg(x)}} ----- (2)$$

substitute (2) into (1)
$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\green{\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} \times\frac{dx}{dg(x)}} \times\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

This leaves you with what you expect:
$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} =\color\green{\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}}$$

You're simply manipulating the LHS to get a form on the RHS that is easily shown by the definition you provided, since the LHS cannot be shown in the definition.

Comment: But isn't that property the chain rule?

Comment: No, they are 2 different things.

Comment: Please see edit. Maybe it helps you understand.

Comment: It seems to me like Chain Rule was used on (2). Anyway, I now realize that using this notation is why I was confused. Using the functional definition the confusion is much easier to avert.